# Do words like phase and space rhyme?

Tags: rhymes

Or is there another way to compare them how they sound similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a word that means "almost rhymes"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215276/is-there-a-word-that-means-almost-rhymes). And see the [Wickipedia Article on half-rhymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_and_imperfect_rhymes): 'Half rhyme or imperfect rhyme, sometimes called near-rhyme, lazy rhyme, or slant rhyme, is a type of rhyme formed by words with similar but not identical sounds. In most instances, either the vowel segments are different while the consonants are identical, or vice versa.'

Comment: And to address the question directly, I would say no, they don't. The s in phase in voiced while the c in space is unvoiced.

Comment: You should look in a dictionary that has a pronunciation guide.